# unable to run my spring boot app using maven?

Tags: linux, spring-boot, docker, ubuntu, docker-compose

I am using the following docker-compose.yml to setup my environment

```
version: "3"
services:
db:
    image: mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_USER: example_db_user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: example_db_pass
    volumes:
      - ./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
    ports:
       - "3306:3306"
 tomcat:
    image: picoded/tomcat7
    environment:
      JDBC_URL: jdbc:mysql://db:3306/data-core?connectTimeout=0&amp;socketTimeout=0&amp;autoReconnect=true
      JDBC_USER: example_db_user
      JDBC_PASS: example_db_pass
    container_name: tomcat7hope
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - ./docker/data-core.war:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/data-core.war

    depends_on:
      - db

  maven:
    build:
      context: .
    depends_on:
      - tomcat
```

My dockerfile is

```
FROM maven:3.5-jdk-8
RUN mvn clean install
```

after running the command docker-compose up the maven container exited saying build failure no goals have been specified for this build.But i already specified RUN mvn clean install in my dockerfile so why is it not running properly??

Comment: May be you have a mistake in pom.xml? The goal can be specified in the build-plugins-plugin section of your pom.xml, depending on what you want to happen with the application.

Comment: I just want to build and run the war file (spring boot app) using maven so do i have to specify the goals as mvn clean install or mvn clean package??

Comment: and do you think I have linked the 3 containers properly?? beacuse the tomcat container has to fetch data from mysql table